# Integral of $\sin(mx)$

Tags: calculus

I've just begun learning $u$-substitution and was looking for an intuition behind how this works.

I was able to get the solution as follows,
$$
\int {\sin (mx)dx} .
$$
Let $mx=t$,
$$
\frac{dt}{dx}=m,\quad dx =\frac{dt}{m}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\int {\sin (mx)dx} = \int {\sin t\frac{{dt}}{m}}  = \frac{1}{m}\int {\sin t\,dt}  =  - \frac{{\cos t}}{m} + c =  - \frac{{\cos (mx)}}{m} + c.
$$
But how could we make changes to the angle. I lack the intuition behind this, any help?

Comment: For the intution : The derivate of $\cos(mx)$ is $-m\cdot \sin(mx)$ , making it easy to determine the antiderivate of $\sin(mx)$. In general, if you have $f(mx+n)$ , then , the antiderivate is $\frac{F(mx+n)}{m}$  , where $F$ is the antiderivate of $f$ , which can easily be proven using the chain-rule.

Comment: @Peter Is this the way it is? Like is integration fundamentally going the reverse of the derivative? I've just started and things look so messed up, is there some solid proof (idk if it makes sense) for u-substitution? Or is this just an algorithm?

Comment: I got it! Everything makes sense now :)

Comment: @Fr0zen That integration is fundamentally going the reverse of the derivative is the most spectacular result of integration theory. It is known as 'The fundamental theorem of calculus' and goes back to Newton.

Comment: @Gribouillis: That's for definite integrals. The fact that computing antiderivatives (like in this question) is the opposite of computing derivatives is rather the least spectacular result of integration theory. :-)

Comment: @HansLundmark Formally speaking, you are correct, but the fact that we use Leibnitz' integral notation to denote antiderivatives shows how tightly it is related to the integral. A proof of the psychological impact of this theorem.